# How do i work with windows media player from another form?

Tags: c#, forms, radio-button, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

So i have 2 forms, one is called "**musica**" and its playing a music (this form is invisible) and the other is called "**Form1**" and gives the option to stop and start the music with radio buttons.

The problem is that the radio buttons are working, but the video continues even if i click on "**radionButton2**" and if i use the "**stop()**" function on "**musica_load**" the music stops so i don't think the problem is from there either.

What is my mistake here?

Form1 code:

```
musica mus = new musica();
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            mus.play();

        }
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            mus.stop();

        }
    }
```

musica code:

```
    public void play()
    {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
    }
    public void stop()
    {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
    }
```

Comment: Does the music play if you click in radionButton1

Comment: No, like the stop() method the play() method doesn't work in Form1..

Answer (score 0):

**// Form1.cs**

```
    musica mus;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mus = new musica();
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            mus.Play(); ;
        }
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            mus.Stop();
        }
    }
```

**//Musica.cs**

```
    public musica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Play");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Stop");
    }
```

This works fine there must be some problem with the Play and Stop methods.

Comment: They work fine in musica.cs, if this method doesn't work do you know a way to do what i want?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** The problem was that i was opennig both forms simultaneously at the start of the program and for some reason they can't work between each other, if i open the **musica.cs** in **Form1_load** everything works!